How to Start Research in Reinforcement Learning for Robotic Manipulators?
I am a graduate student interested in applying artificial intelligence techniques ( specifically reinforcement learning ) to control robotic manipulators (robotic arms).
In order to do this, I don't know where to start studying and decide on a research topic.

What are some foundational papers and resources for understanding this field?
What are some recent reviews or survey papers that can help me understand the current state of the field?
Or are there any papers that I should read in order to study robotics with AI?

Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

I think your post falls into the category "career path recommendation", which is off-topic here. https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. However, asking for resources or references about a specific topic is fine. I'd recommend that you edit your post to 1. ask only one question (not multiple ones), 2. ask a question that can be objectively answered and it not just based on taste or opinions.
